# How to procedurally set Javascript getter/setters? (or actually closure scopes)

Tags: javascript, properties, getter-setter

I'm trying to procedurally add getters/setters to objects in Javascript and although I think the code below should simply work, it doesn't act as I expected.

here is my code:

```
var data = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
function Abc(data) {
    var data = data || {};
    for ( var key in data ) {
        console.log(key, data[key]);
        this.__defineGetter__(key, function() {
                console.log('using getter');
                return data[key];
            })
    }
    return this;
}

abc = Abc(data);
console.log('this should be 1', abc.a);
console.log('this should be 2', abc.b);
console.log('this should be 3', abc.c);
```

and this is my unexpected output

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
using getter
this should be 1 3
using getter
this should be 2 3
using getter
this should be 3 3
```

the output makes absolutely no sense to me, but I get the same output on Chrome and Webkit, so I'm guessing I'm just stupid and this is not a bug of the Javascript engines :)

---

as the comments mention my triple use of "data" isn't really good!

Comment: Don't you want `abc = new Abc(data);`?

Comment: Try putting more diagnostics in the `console.log` to include the key. The closure has only one key I think.

Comment: For starters, you're going to confuse the heck out of yourself when you have three different scoped variables, all with the name `data`.  I'd start by give all three of those (the global `data`, the function parameter `data` and the local variable `data`) different names.  You've blocked access to two of them within that function so you may not be getting what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Robert Gould. main problem in your code sample is not in "defining getters and setters", but in "understanding closures".

- See more about [closures in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Additionaly your code is invalid on using *this* keyword, because your Abc() function *this* object points to global *window* object. You must use *new Abc()* to properly use *this* keyword or must create new empty object inside *Abc()* and return it.

1)

```
function Abc(data) {
  data=data||{};
  for(key in data) {
    console.log(key, data[key]);
    (function(data,key) { // defining closure for our getter function 
      this.__defineGetter__(key, function() {
              console.log('using getter');
              return data[key];
            });
    }).call(this,data,key);
  }
  // dont need to return: when used *new* operator *this* is returned by default
}
var abc = new Abc(data);
```

or
2)

```
function Abc(data) {
  data=data||{};
  var obj={};
  for(key in data) {
    console.log(key, data[key]);
    (function(data,key) { // defining closure for our getter function 
      obj.__defineGetter__(key, function() {
              console.log('using getter');
              return data[key];
            });
    })(data,key);
  }
  return obj; // return object
}
var abc = Abc(data);
```

If you realy need to known about "defining getters|setterns" read about:

- [Object.defineProperty() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [get operator MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/get)
- and for back compatibility [__defineGetter__ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter)
- you must also understand what not all top used browsers currently supports getters and setters for properties

Comment: @Robert Gould - You can mix my examples with code _if(!(this instanceof Abc)) { return new Abc(data); }_ provided by **icktoofay** if needed and when prototype inheritance is important.

Answer (score 3):

By the time the closure that was passed to `__defineGetter__` is executed, the loop has finished and `key` remains at the last value. Try this:

```
function Abc(data) {
    if(!(this instanceof Abc)) {
        return new Abc(data);
    }
    data = data || {};
    for(var key in data) {
        (function(key) {
            console.log(key, data[key]);
            this.__defineGetter__(key, function() {
                console.log('using getter');
                return data[key];
            });
        }).call(this, key);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Some other things:

1. You weren't using `var` on `key`, so `key` was global. That wasn't causing your issue, but it's a good idea to add it anyway.
2. You were declaring a new variable named `data` when there was already a `data` in the scope of the function. It's not needed to use `var` there since there's already a `data` in the function; I removed it.
3. You weren't using `new`, which was also causing odd behavior; the new three lines at the top of the function cause it to act as if it was called with `new`.

Comment: This works! I kind of imagined Javascript's closure were more solid than this, but it gets the job done! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

key is a local variable in the scope of `Abc`, the anonymous function you wrote has no variable key, so it uses the one from the outer scope. That variable has changed to the last value in the loop by the time the anonymous function is used, so you see the last value. You can fix this with a closure:

```
this.__defineGetter__(key, (function(l_key){
    return function() {
        console.log('using getter');
        return data[l_key];
    }
})(key));
```

In that code `l_key` is a local copy of `key` to the anonymous function returned be another anonymous function.